# Working directory diff with Git Extensions

Tags: git, git-extensions

Is there a simple way to get a diff on the working directory using the [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) UI (besides the Commit dialog)?

It feels like View Diff should allow me to diff between my working directory and a commit version.  However it seems to only want to show me my commit history.

I am a recovering [Tortoise Git](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) user, and I'm used to having a "Working Directory" pseduo-commit in my commit log UI.  Is there anything in Git Extensions that works similarly to this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

GitExtensions has a setting to enable the 'pseudo-commit' your mention. Just go to settings, open the tab Git Extensions en check the option 'Show current changes in revision graph'.

This option is disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks for supporting your product via non-standard channels :)  Much appreciated!

Comment: Alas, this pseudo-commit line doesn't allow to do diffs with another branch or revision. :-( Useful tip anyway, so thanks.

Comment: I think this might be out of date, because this Q has attracted some additional answers. Can you update the answer? I have gone command line a long while back, so I can't edit this answer myself and confirm the instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The answer from Henk is great for older versions of GitExtensions. However, I am using version 2.51 and the steps are different. Here are the steps I took:

- On the top ribbon, go to Tools --> Settings

[image]

- Find the "Git Extensions" list item and check the box for "Show current working directory changes an an artificial commit"

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In latest versions (I have version 3.3.0) this option is moved from settings to `View -> Show artificial commits` menu.

You will see local changes when select `Working directory` pseudo-commit in commit graph.

Answer (score 1):

In version 3.00.00.4433 the setting is found here:

`Tools->Settings->Git Extensions->General`

`Show current working directory changes as an artificial commit`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the options that some of you have mentioned here, but what worked for me was the following.

Right click on any commit and go for **View > Show artificial commits** and ensure you disable it.

[image]